# sonata admin use two entities in an admin

Tags: php, symfony, entity-relationship, sonata-admin, query-builder

im new to sonata admin, is this possible to use two entities in one admin class?

my User entity,

App\MyBundle\Entity\Users.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
 */
private $email;
```

my UserProject entity,

App\MyBundle\Entity\UserProjects.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $userid;

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="projectId", type="array")
 */
private $projects;
```

my Admin class,

```
class UserAdmin extends SonataUserAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
         $formMapper
        ->with('General') // these fields from Users Entity
            ->add('username')
            ->add('email')

         ->with('Projects') // these fields from UserPrjects Entity

         /* here i need to add a field for projects related to current user */
      }
  }
```

is there any way to get these two entities connect together?

Comment: You shouldn't name your variables like `userid`. Simply `user` will suffice. Then, I believe, entities should be singular, as in `User`, not `Users`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to add a One-To-Many in the User side:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserProjects", mappedBy="userid")
 */
protected $userProjects;
```

The you can use the UserProjects entity.

Comment: Yes, and don't forget to add correct `addUserProject()` and `removeUserProject()` methods to user entity. This way you can use `$formMapper->add('userProjects', 'sonata_type_collection',
            array(
                'by_reference' => false,
            ),
            array(
                'edit'   => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
            )
        );` in your admin.